# Unable to use !wget on my jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, wget

I was trying to finish up my project on choropleth which involves using !wget to retrieve the json file. Initially, errors stating that several dll files were not located. Therefore, I downloaded it from the internet and placed it over the wget directory. It settled that but now when I try to run my code to retrieve the json file. There is an application error stating "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)."

I've tried to restarted the pc and reinstalled the GNU. nothing seems to work.

```
#wget was unable to run

!wget --quiet https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson -0 sf.json
```

Comment: What about just downloading the json manually and...not using wget?

Answer (score 5):

I'd change the code to the following form:

```
import wget
wget.download('https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson', 'sf.json')
```

hope this helps.